# I need help parsing txt using any script

Tags: python, parsing, shell, csv

I need it help with shell script, python script or anything that can do this. I want to create a script that can parse the following information from a "txt" file to csv. Info I need to parse for my online grade book is to take the username and the lab score. The lab score can be found on this line

```
Your score for this lab: 20/20
```

and  the username can be found on this line

```
Student: username0
```

Thank you for reading and helping me!

Here is the example of the file test.txt

```
Student: username0

Your score for this lab: 20/20

Score Breakdown:
info...

Part 1:


Part 2:


Part 3:

------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
Student: username1

Your score for this lab: 20/20

Score Breakdown:
info...


Part 1:


Part 2:


Part 3:

------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
Student: username2

Your score for this lab: 20/20

Score Breakdown:



Part 1:


Part 2:


Part 3:

------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "Please write my code for me." is not the proper voice for this forum.  It should be phrased as "I wrote this, it doesn't quite work, can you help me please?"

Comment: Sorry, I was just lost on which script to use. I have never written a script before, but next time i will make it clear that I don't want my code to be written just a hint would be nice. Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, this is so easy to do in Python, why not share it with you?

```
def filtered(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('Student:') or line.startswith('Your score for this lab:'):
            yield line.rstrip().split()[-1]

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for student, score in zip(*[filtered(f)]*2):
        print(student, score)
```